# USAID Historical Data Access

Tags: usaidopen

I used to come to this website to get some information about the history of Usaid from its documents. But now I'm not being able to find the place to make the search anymore, isn't it possible to do anymore?

Comment: i'm assuming you mean [USAID.gov](https://www.usaid.gov/)? if so, where did you look? what did you do? do you not see the search bar in the footer that is fixed to the bottom of the page?

Answer (score 1):

The data can be found here -:

https://www.datazar.com/project/pa51cbb1f-68ab-4786-b6c8-571f23849bcf

P.S - I work for datazar, an open data library, where people can discover, work with and share data.

Answer (score 1):

Documents for USAID are stored in the [Development Experience Clearinghouse](https://dec.usaid.gov/dec/home/Default.aspx) (DEC).